# Who’s is the chosen one?

Tags: star-wars

I think the chosen one is Luke in episode 4-6 but it was anakin in 1-3 when he turned to the darkside he lost the title,but since Luke and Leila were born one of those two would get the title and one who got it was Luke.

Comment: Chosen. Or chosen not. There is no get the title.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! It looks like your question already has an answer. While we have you please take the [tour] and check out the [help]. Share and enjoy!

Comment: Rey, according to Kathleen Kennedy